# Get the hidden input when clicking on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need a little help about how to do it..

I have done lot of search but haven't find it.. So please if someone can help me out.

I have this little code here:-

```
<div id="whats-new-content">
  <div class="newtextbox">
    <textarea class="mytextbox" id="myuniquetextbox" cols="50" rows="10" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="whats-new-options" style="display: none;">
    <input type="submit" name="aw-whats-new-submit" id="aw-whats-new-submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i added style="display: none;" in the div where is situated the submit button.

I don't have lot of knowledge in jQuery or javascript but i need a simple javascript code that will change the "display:none" to "display:block" when someone click on the textbox..

Please i need your help, thank you very much...

Comment: Have you tired anything which fails ?

Comment: did you try my answer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is:

```
$(function () {
   $('#myuniquetextbox').click(function(e) {
      $('#whats-new-options').css('display', 'block');
   });
});
```

Comment: this one work greate.. but need to click 2 time when using firefox to make button appear

Comment: @YasSeen did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#myuniquetextbox").on("focus",function(){
  $("#whats-new-options").show();
})
```

Comment: you should use `click` event instead

Comment: @Pepo_rasta focus is what he wants. click makes no sense when navigating with keyboard.

Comment: @YasSeen here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1eyg7msn/ I think you are not running code after page load

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 $("#mytextbox").focus(function() {

    // this is when textarea is focused and button should show
    $("#whats-new-options").show();

    });
```

​

```
$("#mytextbox").blur(function() {

    // this is when textarea is not focused and button should hide
    $("#whats-new-options").hide();

    });​
```

Comment: This is exactly what he wants .. whats the reason for downvote.. on `click` event wont be practical and wont make any sense.. if thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

Try using bellow

```
<script>
$("#myuniquetextbox").click(function(){
   $("#aw-whats-new-submit").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#aw-whats-new-submit").hide();
$("#myuniquetextbox").click(function() {
  $("#aw-whats-new-submit").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="whats-new-content">
  <div class="newtextbox">
    <textarea class="mytextbox" id="myuniquetextbox" cols="50" rows="10" style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="whats-new-options" >
    <input type="submit" name="aw-whats-new-submit" id="aw-whats-new-submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
 $(function () {
       $('#myuniquetextbox').on('click',function(e) {
          $('#whats-new-options').css('display', 'block');
       });
    });
```

Check your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sabLyc1o/)